# MySQL Email Compare and Unsubscribe From Do Not Send List

Tags: mysql, database, email, database-design, inner-join

We've started a 'global' e-mail do not send list that we manage ourselves instead of going with our myriad of e-mail newsletter subscribers, and I'm sure several other members will have the same challenges.

Here's the challenge:

Table 1 = [unsub] = unsubscribe list (email only)
Table 2 = [cust] = database of customers and leads

Pseudo Code:

```
Update cust set unsubEmail=1 where {cust.email} = {unsub.email}
```

What would be the correct MySQL syntax to compare both tables and mark them as above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used MySQL but I don't recall braces being part of the syntax.

Also, you shift from "database" to "table". Is "db" the name of a table? If it's really the name of a database, what's the table in that database that contains the email addresses? (Personal opinion: "db" is a very poor name for either a database or a table.)

The standard SQL query would be something like:

```
update mailing_list set unsubEmail=1 where email in (select email from unsub)
```